# Can I use a decorator to loop through nested list?

Tags: python, decorator

I am having to loop through a 2-dimensional grid (rows and columns) repeatedly to execute various functions at each cell in the grid.  Each time I want to apply another to the cells, I have to code the nested loop...

```
for row in rows:
   for col in row:
      func(col)
```

So to avoid repeating myself, I started with this (old school - Python 2.7.x)

```
#version 1
grid = [[1,2,3,],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
def loop(grid,func):
    results = []
    for row in grid:
        for col in row:
            results.append(func(col))
    return results
def func(x):
    return x+1
results = loop(grid,func)
```

output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

To me, passing a function as argument into another function smelled of a decorator use case. But I haven't figured out how to make it work - passing the grid argument into any wrapper function is tripping me up.

The only improvement I've made to the above is using `map`

```
#version 2
def func(x):
    return x+1
def loop(grid,func):
    return map(func,[col for row in grid for col in row])
```

So my question is can it be done using a decorator and how? (**Etiquette alert**: Which is the better way?)

Comment: Hey thanks for cleaning that up, Jonathan... haven't been here in a while and couldn't remember how to format properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can write a decorator to transform a function that works on a single element into one that works on a grid using a nested loop:

```
def gridfunc(func):
    def wrapper(grid):
        results = []
        for row in grid:
            for col in row:
                results.append(func(col))
        return results
    return wrapper

@gridfunc
def foo(x):
    return x+1

grid = [[1,2,3,],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
results = foo(grid)
```

The only downside to this is that the original function `foo` is not (easily) available if you want to run it on a single value rather than a grid of them. If you want to be able to use both versions, you could use `gridfoo = gridfunc(foo)` instead of the `@decorator` syntax.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Somehow in all the decorator examples I reviewed, I must have tried to make it more complicated than necessary. -- You raise a very good point though by indicating if this is really a good use case if I may want to use the function one value... I guess in that case you could create a grid = [value]. But maybe my version isn't so inelegant after all.